# Generalized Inverse Distribution Function is right continuous

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am given the problem,

> For a distribution function $F$, we define $F^{-1}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, where $F^{-1}(x)=\inf \{y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) \geq x\}$. Show $F^{-1}$ is right-continuous.

I know $F: \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ is a right-continuous, non-decreasing function s.t. $\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}F(x)=0$.

To show right-continuous, I want that $\lim_{y \downarrow x}F^{-1}(y)=F^{-1}(x).$

Comment: What is $F^{-1}(0)$ according to your definition?

Comment: Also there is a problem with $F^{-1}(1)$ if $F(y)<1$ for all $y$.  $F^{-1}$ is not  function from $[0,1]$ to \mathbb R$.

Comment: I mean, it would just be $F^{-1}(0)=\inf\{y \in \mathbb{R}: F(y) \geq 0\}$. I have an example of a $F^{-1}$ where  $F^{-1}(0)=0$. Wouldn't it always be $0$? I can describe the example if you want.

Comment: You will have to modify the definition and make some additional assumption on $F$. The result you have claimed is not true. BTW infimum of $\mathb R$ is $-\infty$, not $0$. How did you get $F^{-1}(0)$ as $0$?

Comment: I wonder the same. I've had trouble understanding this definition and example since learning it. I came across a paper https://file.scirp.org/pdf/AM_2012123110083732.pdf showing it isn't right-continuous. I have yet to receive a problem that has a typo or is just wrong, so I'm not too sure what to do. Maybe it meant left-continuous

Comment: Regardless of the problems  at $0,1$ the function on $(0,1)$ would have to be left- not right-continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined $F^{-1}$ actually must be left-continuous.

Fix $a \in (0,1]$ and consider a sequence $x_n \uparrow a$. Since $F^{-1}$ is nondecreasing it follows that

$$y_n =F^{-1}(x_n) \uparrow y \leqslant F^{-1}(a)$$

For any $\epsilon > 0$, we have $F(y_n - \epsilon) < x_n \leqslant F(y_n + \epsilon) $.

Now suppose $y < F^{-1}(a)$.  Taking $\epsilon = (F^{-1}(a)-y)/2$ we get

$$x_n \leqslant F(y_n+ \epsilon) \leqslant F(F^{-1}(a) + \epsilon) < a,$$ since $y_n\leq F^{-1}(a)$

which implies the contradiction $x_n \uparrow a < a$.

Comment: There must be a typo in the given problem then. Thank you.

Comment: @HCS: You're welcome. It should also have the property that right limits exist I believe.

Comment: Hi, could you please show me how can you get to this statement in your answer ? For any $\epsilon > 0$, we have $F(y_n - \epsilon) < x_n \leqslant F(y_n + \epsilon) $. I am struggling to understand how to arrive at that statement. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. In fact, it was the same derivation as mine. But i realize it is not true to claim that $F(F^{-1} (x_n)) = x_n$. It should be $F(F^{-1} (x_n)) \ge x_n$ by definition of $F^{-1}$, which falsifies my derivation. Could you please look into this issue ? thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge:  So that gives immediately $x_n \leqslant F(F^{-1}(x_n)) \leqslant F(y_n + \epsilon)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but the difficult part is to prove $F(y_n - \epsilon) \lt x_n$, could you please show me how to do that ? i am very appreciated your help!

Comment: @RRL : Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Here is my proof: Suppose $F(y_n - \epsilon ) \ge x_n$, then there exists a number $y^{'}_n = y_n - \epsilon \lt y_n$ that makes $F(y^{'}_n) \gt x_n$, which causes the contradiction on the fact that $y_n$ is the infimum. Am i right ? I don't understand why we should consider 2 cases continuous and discontinuous of $F$, could you kindly explain that to me please ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: That is correct.  You don't need to consider continuity. I was about to write: Let $y_n = F^{-1}(x_n) = \inf \{y:F(y) \geqslant x_n\}$.  Then $y_n \leqslant y$ for all $y$ such that $F(y) \geqslant x_n$.  If $F(y_n-\epsilon) \geqslant x_n$, then  $y_n \leqslant y_n - \epsilon$ -- a contradiction.

Comment: ... and that is why we have the strict inequality $F(y_n - \epsilon) < x_n $ on the left. I was trying to remember why I wrote it that way as opposed to $F(y_n - \epsilon) \leqslant x_n \leqslant F(y_n + \epsilon)$.